# How is rustc able to compile source code from bash process substitution but gcc cannot?

Tags: c, linux, bash, unix, rust

```
$ rustc <(echo 'fn main(){ print!("Hello world!");}')
$ ls
63
$ gcc <(echo '#include<stdio.h> int main(){ printf("Hello world!\n"); return 0;}')
/dev/fd/63: file not recognized: Illegal seek
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why can't `ld` link the program?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164107/why-does-bash-process-substitution-not-work-with-some-commands

Comment: Gcc is a Compiler Collection. If you don't specify the language with `-x c` (for C or with something else), it doesn't know what backend to use since there's no file extension to tell it, so it has to inspect the file. It does it by seeking, because read-ing might irreversibly consume a single shot stream and seeking fails on single shot streams (bash process substitution creates FIFO -- single-shot streams) and so it fails.

Comment: Ahh -- invoking `ld` (treating it as an object file) does explain things.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yeah, I used strace to track down the error, and it is indeed coming from `ld` (via `collect2`). The logic is that `ld` tries various ways to interpret the file, falling back on "linker script". But since it can't rewind the file, it doesn't actually manage to do the tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `gcc` command is mostly a dispatch engine. For each input file, it determines what sort of file it is *from the filename's extension*, and then passes the file on to an appropriate processor. So `.c` files are compiled by the C compiler, `.h` files are assembled into precompiled headers, `.go` files are sent to the cgo compiler, and so on.

If the filename has no extension or the extension is not recognised, `gcc` assumes that it is some kind of object file which should participate in the final link step. These files are passed to the `collect2` utility, which then invokes `ld`, possibly twice. This will be the case with process substitution, which produces filenames like `/dev/fd/63`, which do not include extensions.

`ld` does not rely on the filename to identify the object file format. It is generally built with several different object file recognisers, each of which depends on some kind of "magic number" (that is, a special pattern at or near the beginning of the file). It calls these recognisers one at a time until it finds one which is happy to interpret the file. If the file is not recognised as a binary format, `ld` assumes that it is a linker script (which is a plain text file) and attempts to parse it as such.

Naturally, between attempts `ld` needs to rewind the file, and since process substitution arranges for a pipe to be passed instead of a file, the seek will fail. (The same thing would happen if you attempted to pass the file through redirection of stdin to a pipe, which you can do: gcc will process `stdin` as a file if you specify `-` as a filename. But it insists that you tell it what kind of file it is. See below.)

Since `ld` can't rewind the file, it will fail after the file doesn't match its first guess. Hence the error message from `ld`, which is a bit misleading since you might think that the file has already been compiled and the subsequent failure was in the link step. That's not the case; because the filename had no extension, `gcc` skipped directly to the link phase and almost immediately failed.

In the case of process substitution, pipes, stdin, and badly-named files, you can still manually tell `gcc` what the file is. You do that with the `-x` option, which is documented in the [GCC manual section on options controlling the kind of output](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html) (although in this case, the option actually controls the kind of input).

There are a number of answers to questions like this floating around the Internet, including various answers here on StackOverflow, which claim that GCC attempts to detect the language of input files. It does not do that, and it never has. (And I doubt that it ever will, since some of the languages it compiles are sufficiently similar to each other that accurate detection would be impossible.) The only component which does automatic detection is `ld`, and it only does that once GCC has irrevocably decided to treat the input file as an object file or linker script.

Answer (score 3):

At least in your case, you can use process substition when specifying the input language manually, using `-xc`. However, you should put a newline after the include statement.

```
$ gcc -xc <(echo '#include<stdio.h>
int main(){ printf("Hello world!\n"); return 0;}')
$ ls
a.out
$ ./a.out 
Hello world!
```

For a possible reason why this works, see Charles' answer and the comments on this answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `gcc -c some-fifo.c` does work. Try `rm -f some-fifo.c && mkfifo some-fifo.c; echo '#include<stdio.h>
int main(){ printf("Hello world!\n"); return 0;}' > some-fifo.c & gcc some-fifo.c && ./a.out` (or with `-c` ).

Comment: ...hmm. Think I was actually running on a platform where the gcc binary is a wrapper, not real GCC. Does make sense that we'd only scan file contents if/when the name isn't dispositive.

Comment: Thank you both for the investigations. I shouldn't have made any assumptions for the reasons, therefore I removed my guess.  We should try with bigger and more complicated c programs. Maybe process substitution works only in some cases.

Comment: @Socowi: Process substitution works precisely in the case that you use `-x` to tell GCC which component to use to process the file. GCC is always a wrapper; which is why it is called a "compiler collection".